# Subgroup of order $4$ of matrix group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be the set of all real $\ 2\times 2$ matrices $\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
0 & d
\end{pmatrix}$ where $ad\neq 0$. We know that $G$ forms a group under matrix multiplication. Construct in the $G$ a subgroup of order $4$.

**My solution:** Let $H\subset G$ be the following set $H=\{E,-E,A,-A\}$ where $E=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$ and $A=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$. It's easy to check that $A^2=E$ and $A^{-1}=A$. The set $G$ holds the property of binary operation, existence of inverse and identity elements and the property of associativity.

Hence the set $H$ is the subgroup of $G$ and $|H|=4$.

Right?

Let me ask one question: For the binary operation should we check out all possibillities by hand? It's annoying :)

Comment: Are $a,b,d\in \mathbb{F}_q$ for a prime power $q$? For $q=2$ we only get the trivial group.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, your comments is always difficult :) I do not know what is $\mathbb{F}_q$

Comment: $\mathbb{F_q}$ is a field with $q$ elements, example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GF(2), is $\mathbb{F_2}$

Comment: @DietrichBurde,So what? We are talking $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Yes, now it says real:)

Answer (score 3):

Your reasoning is correct, since the group $G$ consists of real matrices.

Comment: ..... and that is a reason for downvote ?? A usual style in Austria ?

Comment: Dietrich, dann entschuldige ich mich !

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is correct **except** in the case where the field from which you take $a, b, d$ has characteristic $2$; in that case you have $1 = -1$, and all your matrices $E, -E, A, -A$ are identical.

Comment: I do not know what is the characteristic of the field. I am in the begining of group theory from the book of Herstein.

Comment: @RFZ: Okay, but even in that book the author should say a few things about what $a, b, d$ are, right?

Comment: $a,b,d$ are real numbers

Comment: and the characteristic of real numbers is $0$

Comment: @RFZ: Oops, you're right; it says so in the OP; I had missed that - sorry. In that case your argument is right (since $1\ne -1$).